# Wait for SSH tunnel before continuing a script

Tags: mysql, bash, ssh, cloud-foundry, tunnel

I have a script that dumps data from a cloud foundry db, and it works in the following way:

```
cf ssh -L 33001:db.host:3306 --skip-remote-execution App &
TUNNEL_PID=$!

mysqldump --protocol TCP --port= 33001 ..... db_name > /tmp/my-db-dump.sql

kill $TUNNEL_PID
```

The problem is that `mysqldump` fails with

> mysqldump: Got error: 2003: Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' (61) when trying to connect

I expect that the problem is that the tunnel is not established yet. When I do `sleep 5` before mysqldump, everything works. But I don't want to rely on random 5 seconds. Is it possible to wait for the tunnel to get started?

Answer (score 1):

Can you run mysqldump via the ssh command, instead of opening a tunnel?

Mysqldump will write to its stdout, which will be transferred back to your client host via the ssh command.

```
ssh App "mysqldump db_name" > /tmp/my-db-dump.sql
```

Or you could even dump to a compressed file on the server, and then fetch the dump file with scp. That will help the transfer to go faster.

```
ssh App "mysqldump db_name | gzip -c > /tmp/my-db-dump.sql.gz"
scp App:/tmp/my-db-dump.sql.gz .
ssh App "rm /tmp/my-db-dump.sql.gz"
```

This is untested, but I hope it gives you some ideas to experiment with.

Comment: With `cf ssh` you do this slightly different than standard SSH.  Instead of `ssh <host> "command"`, it's `cf ssh <app-name> -c "command"`.  Alternatively, you can use standard `ssh`/`scp`/`sftp`, but the commands are a little messy -> https://github.com/cloudfoundry/diego-ssh#cloud-foundry-via-cloud-controller-and-uaa

Comment: Thanks for the tip @DanielMikusa, I'll leave my examples as "pseudocode." :-)